# How to select rows in data.table by matching conditions with a vector

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data.table:

```
dt1 <- data.table(A=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,2,3),
                  B=c(8,4,3,1,1,5,9,7,1,1),
                  C=c(11,11,11,12,12,12,13,13,14,14))
```

and vector:

`dt_filter <- c(1,2,3)`

I would like to select `C` column in `dt1` which column `A` contains all the values in vector `dt_filter`.

so the return is `11` and `12`.

I have come up with the following code, but I do not think it is efficient enough:

`dt1[, sum(A %in% dt_filter) == 3, by = C][V1 == T, C]`

Could you please give some suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Filter across all groups first (otherwise you're running separate filters on each group, which is inefficient since there is some overhead to doing so):

```
dt1[A %in% 1:3, if (.N == 3L) TRUE, keyby = C]$C
```

If `A` may not be unique within `C`:

```
dt1[A %in% 1:3, if (length(unique(A)) == 3L) TRUE, keyby = C]$c
```

Pre-sorting may help:

```
setkey(dt1, A)
dt1[.(1:3), if (.N == 3L) TRUE, keyby = C]$C
```

Can also combine with `unique`:

```
unique(dt1[.(1:3)], by = c('A', 'C'))[ , if (.N == 3L) TRUE, keyby = C]$C
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dt1[, .(check = all(dt_filter %in% A)), by = C][check == TRUE, C]
```

I think this will cover it off better, as your method will check if there are any 3, but the data implies things can be repeated, so if C = 13 had A = 1,1,2 then we would potentially break